# Wrong architecture issue on virtual environment Apple M1 Chip

Tags: python, virtualenv, apple-m1, ujson

I have been trying to run my django project on my new macbook Apple M1 Chip machine but only to encounter the error below.
I have tried to ensure that arch command returns i386 on both pycharm and system terminal but still not working.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/harmankibue/.virtualenvs/wwsb_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/srsly/ujson/ujson.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/harmankibue/.virtualenvs/wwsb_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/srsly/ujson/ujson.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/harmankibue/.virtualenvs/wwsb_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/srsly/ujson/ujson.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: Hi friend, can you share how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,
Go to **Application** folder -> Right click on **Terminal** App -> **Get Info**

Tick **Open with Rosetta** option.
build the project now.

Answer (score 0):

I had Python 3.8.10 in my mac OS and was facing this same error after installing numpy version 1.21.x.

Reinstalling numpy with a lower version of 1.19.2 worked for me and I stopped seeing such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Intel .dmg version of PyCharm solved this issue for me, after trying lots of ways all through the day